# How to write a cached variable evaluator?

Tags: r

Edit:

I have a kludgy piece of code that looks like this:

```
readcsvfile()
dopreprocessingoncsvfile()
readanothercsvfile()
moreprocessing()
# etc ...
```

Over a few days, this has gradually got longer and more complex, and therefore takes over a minute or two to run now, and I'm not very patient :-P .  Given that R is so great at saving the environment, I mean the variables in the R environment, an easy way to accelerate this is:

```
if( !exists("init.done") {
readcsvfile()
dopreprocessingoncsvfile()
readanothercsvfile()
moreprocessing()
init.done = T
}
```

However, I like it to be a bit more fine-grained, not least because sometimes I might tweak a function in the processing, so I want to rerun it, without watching the whole world reload, so I've changed it to:

```
if( !exists("somedata" ) ) {
    somedata <- readcsvfile()
}
# ... etc ... same for the others
```

However, sometimes I make one of the following mistakes, and let's face it, I'm also just plain lazy, so why write a big long if statement if there is a more concise way?  I make the following mistakes often:

- mistype the name of the variable in the if, which 'detects' itself by my noticing that it keeps running every time I run the script
- miss off the second bracket in the if clause, which takes 10-15 seconds to detect, modify, and rerun, which is annoying :-P

Sooo.... my proposd solution is to write a function `cacheVar` whose definition looks a bit like:

```
cacheVar <- function( varname, expression ) {
    if( !exists(varname ) {
        setValueMagic( varname, evalMagic(expression) )
    }
}

... and whose usage looks like:

cacheVar("foo", {
    # some expression that calculates the value of foo
})
```

... where the expression is evaluated only if value 'varname' doesn't already exist.

I guess the missing information to flesh this out is:

- does this exist already?
- how to write `setValueMagic` in R?
- how to write `evalMagic` in R?

Edit: a bit more complicated, since we need to assign into the parent frame, possibly using `parent.env` or `parent.frame`, something like that.

Comment: This seems like a bit of a kludge. Can you provide more context for the actual problem you're trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: You could try using `lockBinding` to protect variables from being overwritten, though as it throws an error, you may have to then use `try` when attempting to assign.

Comment: There's also `mget`, which looks for a variable by name, returning what you supply to its `ifnotfound` arg, if the variable doesn't exist. Maybe you could use this in your situation instead of 'caching' the variable? Otherwise, I suspect what you've written in your question is as clear and terse as you're going to get.

Comment: @mplourde, does `setValue` actually exist?  That's just a made-up name I put in, along the lines of writing `magic`

Comment: @Joshua, edited the question to add lots of background on the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: `knitr` has caching of results of chunks of code which could be leveraged to do this, even if you are not interested in creating a second (HTML, LaTeX, etc.) document at the same time.

Comment: @mplourde, `mget` looks like what I need.  Now I just to figure out the environment bit.  I thought that `assign` is what I need, but since this is a function, then assign only assigns to the function scope, so I probably need to assign to parent.env, or something like that, using `mget`

Comment: @Hugh `assign` has an `envir` arg that you could supply with `parent.frame()`. You'll probably want to set the `inherits` arg to `TRUE`, also.